# How to start tmux with several panes open at the same time?

Tags: tmux

Suppose I start `tmux` and immediately execute <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>.

This gives me a tall pane on the left side of the screen; the right side of the screen has a top and bottom pane.

How can I configure tmux to start in this configuration without having to type these commands?

Comment: If your requirement is to open a few terminals all at once in a single click you can do it with **terminator**. Install it from software center.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good command to know!  For my particular case, this is for an ssh session to a remote computer.

Comment: Terminator is not a session handler.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Another option is to create an alias or another shell file in `/bin` for:

```
tmux new-session \; split-window -h \; split-window -v \; attach
```

or

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

where `~/.tmux.conf`

```
new
neww
splitw -h
splitw -v
```

For reference, same question has other options in SE, [How to set up tmux so that it starts up with specified windows opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609192/how-to-set-up-tmux-so-that-it-starts-up-with-specified-windows-opened)

Comment: A note to others, the above answer only works inside a pre-existing `tmux` session. To execute this from a generic terminal session perform the following command: `tmux new-session -s <SESSION_NAME> "tmux source-file '$~/.tmux.conf'"`. You should alias this command to a `bash` function for convenience. Your `tmux.conf` should contain the content listed in the answer above.

Answer (score 23):

You can use following shell script for your configuration:

```
#!/bin/sh 
tmux new-session -s "mySession" -d
tmux split-window -h
tmux split-window -v
tmux -2 attach-session -d
```

This will give the required configuration of the screen with following commands as you mentioned.
tmux --> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> --> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>

For reference please use [tmux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html).

Comment: unfortunately the ~/.bashrc does not seems to be executed in all panes, I lost my aliases with this solution.

Answer (score 6):

The [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) plugin will enable setting up session persistence as well as provide additional functionality for saving and restoring settings across tmux sessions.

Many additional features are available with this plugin. From the plugin's project page:

> *This plugin goes to great lengths to save and restore all the details from your tmux environment. Here's what's been taken care of:*
>
> - all sessions, windows, panes and their order
> - current working directory for each pane
> - exact pane layouts within windows (even when
>     zoomed)
> - active and alternative session
> - active and alternative window for each session
> - windows with focus active pane for each window
> - "grouped sessions" (useful feature when using tmux with multiple
>     monitors) programs running within a pane! "

**Installation:**

1. In the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), navigate to your tmux plugin directory(in my
       case, `~/dotfiles/tmux/plugins`).
2. Clone the repository with the command: `git clone https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect`.
3. Edit your `.tmux.conf` file and add the line `set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect'`.
4. Reload the tmux environment with the command: `tmux source-file ~/dotfiles/tmux/tmux.conf`.
5. Enter the layout that you want. In this case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>%</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>.
6. Save your tmux session by entering the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>.
7. When you next start your tmux session, enter the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> to restore your tmux session.

As mentioned previously, in addition to setting up the pane layout of the tmux session, this plugin can also set up persistent working directories as well as have your running applications restart with each session.

Comment: thx for sharing

Answer (score 5):

It can be easy to enable and disable automatic `tmux` sessions on login by using [Byobu](https://byobu.org/) application. You can use Byobu as an interface to `tmux` to address this need, it makes it simple to do what you are asking. In a terminal, run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install byobu
sudo byobu-enable
sudo -i
```

When the root user logs in via the console, SSH, or with `sudo -i`, Byobu will attach to an existing `tmux` session or create a new one if one is not already running. Use **`sudo -i`** instead of `sudo -s`. The `-s` option only starts a shell, not a login shell. You should use `sudo -i` to emulate a full login, which also loads `roots ~/.profile`, and this is where byobu will install itself when you run

`byobu-enable`.

**You can configure different sessions from your `.tmux.conf` as below:**

```
# initialize sessions
bind S source-file ~/.tmux/session1 
bind s source-file ~/.tmux/session2
```

And then you can format the sessions as you require:

```
#session1
new  -s SessionName -n WindowName Command
neww -n foo/bar foo
splitw -v -p 50 -t 0 bar
selectw -t 1 
selectp -t 0
```

This would open 2 windows, the second of which would be named foo/bar and would be split vertically in half (50%) with foo running above bar. Focus would be in window 2 (foo/bar), top pane (foo).

Byobu makes setting up and starting tmux automatically very simple.

Comment: why `bind S`  vs `bind s`? (first large S, then small s?)

Comment: @knb `bind` in this case is a tmux configuration command. He's just creating two tmux commands that are bound to s and then S. You can choose other combinations if you like. Doing this allows you to effectively run the tmux commands specified in the files by key combinations while inside a tmux session

Answer (score 3):

I wrote myself a little *bash* script:

```
# filename tmuxv in /home/<username>/Bash/tmuxv/

#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session \; split-window -v \; rename-window ${1} \; attach
```

and put an *alias* in my ~/.bash_aliases

```
alias tmuxv="/home/<username>/Bash/tmuxv/tmuxv"
```

So now I can simply type `tmuxv PYTHON` and I have a vertically split tmux session with a window named PYTHON, which is nice because the window name gets reflected in my gnome-terminals tab name.

Comment: Good answer, but please remove the question at the end. Try asking it as a new question, which will make sure more people see it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a .bash_aliases function that opens up a tall pane on the left and splits the right pane vertically (see picture below).

"-t $SESSION:1.2"  indicates you want to execute the command in the "work" session, in the first window, in the second pane (<prefix + q> lists pane numbers).

"G" is the vim command that takes you to the end of the file.

```
openSession () {

    WORK_DIR="~/projects"
    SESSION="work"

    tmux kill-session -t $SESSION
    tmux new-session -d -s $SESSION
    tmux split-window -h -t $SESSION:1.1
    tmux split-window -v -t $SESSION:1.2
    tmux send-keys -t $SESSION:1.1 "cd $WORK_DIR && vim notes" Enter
    tmux send-keys -t $SESSION:1.1 "G" Enter
    tmux send-keys -t $SESSION:1.3 "cd $WORK_DIR && ll" Enter
    tmux attach-session -t $SESSION
}
```

[image]